# how to specify query string in url with apache bench

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, thin, apachebench

My rails application is running on thin server which i want to benchmark using apachebench

the command am using is

```
ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:3001/welcome/search?query="doctor"&rad=5
```

But thin server is not taking this url.Its giving

```
!! Invalid Request
```

Can any one help me how to give the url such that thin accepts the url with query string

Answer (score 30):

apache benchmark wont resolve "localhost" out of the url. change it to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 and quote the whole url to avoid problems with the ampersand. eg:

```
ab -n 1 -c 1 "http://0.0.0.0:3001/welcome/search?query=doctor&rad=5"
```

Answer (score 5):

Your query string is not properly encoded. Remove the double quote. If it's needed, you need to send it like this,

```
ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:3001/welcome/search?query=%22doctor%22&rad=5
```

Comment: yeah you were right.I removed double quote so Invalid request is resolved. NOw suppose my query is http://localhost:3001/welcome/search?query=%22medical%20college%22&rad=5   ,medical is taken but college is not considered, value 5 of rad is not taken by thin; i even tried with substituting & with %26 it didnt work.

Comment: & is interpredet as a shell parameter. You can put the whole URL in quotes and it will work: `ab -n 1 -c 1 "http://localhost:3001/welcome/search?query=%22doctor%22&rad=5"`

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work with ApacheBench2.  I am trying the following:
ab2 -n 8000 -c 100 "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000?jsonp=callbackFunction&articeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F2010%2FCRIME%2F08%2F30%2Fclemens.case%2Findex.html%2F"

Getting an "invalid URL" error!

Comment: as pointed out the problem is the ampersand, the other answer (using double quotes around the url) works.

Answer (score 3):

This was not working for me, though this line did work:

```
ab -n 1 -c 1 -B 127.0.0.1 "http://localhost:3001/some/stuff"
```

*Mind the casing!*

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.